# extract ip address from a string containing ip address and other alphnum

Tags: bash

Say I have this

```
str="System IP is 9.9.9.9 on port 3442"
str2="ip 192.168.0.9 is using port 222"
```

I would like to remove all substrings except for the one which contains periods which would leave me with :

```
9.9.9.9 
192.168.0.9
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Its duplicate question, you can use `grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'` to get the IP substring from the main string

Comment: oh duh I see what you are saying ...

Comment: @PS. thanks for some reason it wasn't obvious to me until you pointed it out .. thanks